# Is there a way to embed file ask directory in a tkinter frame?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-layout

I am new to tkinter and would like to know if there is a way to embed a directory listing to a frame in my GUI. The purpose of embedding is to automatically display all the images in the folder on to an another frame when it is selected by user.

Th following image shows what I would like to achieve:

[image: screenshot of desired interface]

Comment: there is no standard widget to display it. You would have to create own widget to display list with names using Listbox or tree directory using [TreeView](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/tree.html). You will have to read filenames and fill widgets on your own. OR use Google "tkinter directory tree" to find external modules or examples how to do it.

Comment: You can also subclass `tkinter.filedialog.FileDialog` which gives a basic file/directory display. It might be easier to do so instead of building a new one.